# JavaScript Debugger engine

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing

I would like to create a JavaScript testing tool. Instead of creating an interpreter which increase the complexity of the tool, there is the possibility to call an existing debugger, for example, those integrated with Chrome and Firefox? For example, suppose to have:

```
function foo (a, b) {
  return (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

**There is the possibility to execute this function with some parameters from an external application?** In this way, I can execute the function with different parameters and keep the status of a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following line in your javascript where you want to break into the debugger:

```
debugger;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and adding this line means I break into VS at that point and can see the variables, execute commands in the current context etc.

EDIT: Without an IDE you may be a little bit stuck as the F12 tools require explicit opening, from what I've read.
You could write a global javascript logger that will log the members of any object passed to a failing method, it could even be an AJAX call to the server-side code and write it in C# with reflection to get all the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to use an IDE for the debug but I would like to query an existing debugger and call it from an external application.

Comment: Like the Chrome F12 tools? Chrome will not - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277  - "We only allow explicit devtools opening."

Comment: I found debugging protocol for Chrome and Firefox but I don't find the communication protocol that they use.

Comment: @Marco Did you see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol ?